# Collapse some repeated parts of successive lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have data in notepad like this:

```
4480-1
4480-2
4480-3
4480-15
4581-1
4581-2
4581-3
4581-4
```

Can we do it using for loop sort of things? With sed?

My required output is `4480-1&-2&-3&-15&4581-1&-2&-3&-4`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
awk -F- '$1!=a{printf "%s", $1} {printf "-%s&", $2} {a=$1}' file | sed 's/&$/\n/g'
```

Outout:

```
4480-1&-2&-3&-15&4581-1&-2&-3&-4
```

**Explanantion:**

- `awk -F-` delimiter is `-`
- `$1!=a{printf "%s", $1}` print the first part `4480` if it's not the same as in the last processed line
- `{printf "-%s&", $2}` print the second part with `&` at the end
- `{a=$1}` set a to the processed line
- `sed 's/&$/\n/g'` remove the last character that is a `&` and add a newline

Answer (score 1):

I dont' think you can do it with `sed` easily. It's easier with `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'-' -anle '
    $h{$F[0]} .= defined($h{$F[0]}) ? "&-".$F[1] : "-".$F[1];
    END {
        $,="&";
        print @{[map { $_.$h{$_} } sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h]}
    }
' file
4480-1&-2&-3&-15&4581-1&-2&-3&-4
```

Comment: The output is slightly different than the one in the question, when the next starting number is encountered, there shouldn't be an & at first.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Try again, I still editting my answer when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not possible with sed. I'm doing with AWK.
I assume one entry per line.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS="-"; ORS=""; left="" }

  {
    if(NR>1){print "&"}

    # Only print left part if it differs from previous line
    if ($1!=left) {
      print $1 "-" $2
      left=$1;
    } else {
      print "-" $2
    }
  }' inputfile.txt
```

Outputs `4480-1&-2&-3&-15&4581-1&-2&-3&-4`

Answer (score 0):

If your input isn't really sorted as in the question, you should use `sort -n file`, first.

```
awk '
{
    split($1, id, "-")

    if (NR > 1) {
        printf "&"
    }

    if (prefix_test[id[1]]++ == 0) {
        printf("%s", id[1])
    }

    printf("-%s", id[2])
}

END { printf "\n" }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be sed, however here is perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ( ($a,$b) = split /-/,<>) { $n->{$a}->{"-$b"}++;}

@_ = map { $_,
           map { chomp; "$_&"; } reverse sort { $a <=> $b } keys $n->{$_};
     } sort { $a <=> $b } keys $n;

@_[-1] =~ s/&$//;

print @_;
```

numerically sorted output, not depending the input order:

```
4480-1&-2&-3&-15&4581-1&-2&-3&-4
```

Comment: Thanks chaos..it's working. i have one more requirement like, in a note pad above data comes between 2 lines like "VMG100" & "VMG102",this thing keeps on going... i want format as VMG100 & above output....VMG101 followed by (output to some other data)

Comment: Yu're welcome. It would be nice when you post a new question belonging to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution that doesn't require the entries to be sorted by prefix

```
awk -F- '
    {a[$1] = !a[$1]? $1"-"$2 : a[$1]"&-"$2} 
END {asort(a); for (i in a) printf "%s&", a[i]}
' file | sed 's/&$/\n/'
```

If you don't need the *output* to be sorted, you can omit the `asort(a)`

```
awk -F- '
    {a[$1] = !a[$1]? $1"-"$2 : a[$1]"&-"$2} 
END {for (i in a) printf "%s&", a[i]}
' file | sed 's/&$/\n/'
```